# iOS equivalent values of Android's Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, android-sensors, sensors

I'm working on a cross-platform augmented-reality library, my Android code works great, but I'm having trouble with iOS.  I'm using Android's [TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) sensor, which produces a [SensorEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent). This event returns an array of 5 values (as described [here](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-c-motion-and-position-sensors/3-2-c-motion-and-position-sensors.html)), which are used to generate a rotation matrix (using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrixFromVector(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) method). I'm only really interested in the first 4 values. They're described as:

> SensorEvent.values[0] x *sin(θ/2)
>
> SensorEvent.values[1] y *sin(θ/2)
>
> SensorEvent.values[2] z *sin(θ/2)
>
> SensorEvent.values[3] cos(θ/2)

The aforementioned [link](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-c-motion-and-position-sensors/3-2-c-motion-and-position-sensors.html) goes on to say

> The rotation-vector sensor (TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) provides the
> orientation of the device with respect to Earth's coordinate system as
> a unit quaternion. Specifically, the rotation vector represents the
> orientation of the device as a combination of an angle and an axis, in
> which the device has rotated through an angle θ around an axis < x , y
> , z >. The first four elements of the rotation vector are equal to the
> components of a unit quaternion x sin(θ/2), y sin(θ/2), z
> *sin(θ/2)>. The elements of the rotation vector are unitless.

CoreMotion in iOS provides a [quaternion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitude/1616025-quaternion) reading, but it doesn't seem to correlate to Android's TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR values (at least not directly). I've also tried deviceMotion's `attitude.rotationMatrix` value directly, but it's not useful.

So my question is: in iOS, how can I obtain sensor values equivalent to Android's TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this eventually?